# How are escape sequences contributing to the length of a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, printing, escaping

```
a=("\nHello")
print(len(a))
```

The intended output is a new line with 5 printed but instead there is no new line and the length is coming out to be 6.

Answer (score 4):

There is a new line printed, plus the 5 characters in 'Hello', that's 6 in total:

```
a = "\nHello"
print(a)
print("Total length is", len(a))
```

Output

```
<space>
Hello
Total length is 6
```